# Не получается запустить Eclipse под отладкой, (использую idea) нет класса main как в обычных проектах

Tags: java, intellij-idea, github, eclipse

изучаю Java, и задался целью запустить opensource проект у себя на машине, с целью обучения. выбор пал на Eclipse. Нашел репозиторий платформы в github: https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.platform.ui   но не получается запустить его под отладкой, (использую idea) нет класса main как в обычных проектах.

Может у меня слишком наивный подход, и вообще такое сделать невозможно?

Answer (score 0):

Да, запуск таких больших проектов обычно не такой простой, нужно читать документацию. На Github обычно указывают эту информацию в `Readme.md`.

В данном случае, для сборки требуется `maven` и с помощью него надо выполнить команду

```
mvn clean verify -Pbuild-individual-bundles
```